# Label edits disappear upon saving?

Tags: shapefile, labeling, qgis-2, windows-10

I am trying to label a map I'm creating in QGIS v 2.8.9. I'm using data defined labeling to both manually place and rotate labels. I've created the required fields (X, Y, and Rotate) all as decimal with a width of 10. Up to today, I've had no problem editing the labels and saving these edits. However, today, upon moving some labels, and subsequently saving the edits, all the labels (edited today, not earlier edits) snapped back to their original positions. Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see the labels for the lakes all show highlighted because they are now pinned since I edited them. Now, when I save the layer edits, this happens:

[image]

The labels snap back to their pre-edited positions.

All my layers are shapefiles and have not been touched in ArcGIS at any point if that helps. Also, it seems to only be affecting labels. I can still edit and save polygon, point, and line features.

Comment: QGIS 2.8.9 is fairly old, could you perhaps try downloading a more recent version (e.g. QGIS 2.14.3) and see if the problem persists?

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem for now. Thank you!

Comment: Most welcome, you should post an **answer** mentioning that your problem was solved using whichever QGIS version you downloaded =)